# What does the message following error message in visual studio mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

So I am creating a multi-threaded C++ program and it returns this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x77e915de in HANASimulationSync.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020.

By the way, when I run this code in a single thread it doesn't return any errors.  I'd just like to know what sort of error is this?  Does it have something to do with memory management?

Comment: Y U NO POST CODE??????

Comment: @TonyTheLion "I'd just like to know what sort of error is this?"

Comment: That is a runtime-error, more commonly known as a "crash". What you should do is run your program in the debugger. The debugger will then stop when the crash happens, and you can examine variables and see the function call stack. If the code shown is not your, then step up in the call-stack until you come to your code.

Comment: It means you got a **Segmentation Fault**.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Comment: well without no code i can say it means there's an unhandled exception at 0x77e915de in HANASimulationSync.exe and the reason is most likely an access violation reading location 0x00000020.

Comment: If it only happens when you run multiple threads, it's most likely that you don't protect some share resource, i.e. two or more threads modify the same thing at the same time. Read about e.g. mutexes or semaphores to help you with that.

Answer (score 14):

It means that you attempted to read from an invalid memory location. In this case the location was `0x00000020`. Since that is just a small offset above zero, it seems that you are probably de-referencing an offset from a null pointer.

So, a common way to see something like this would be if you had a struct with a member at offset `0x20`. And then if you tried to read that member from a pointer to a struct where the pointer was null. And you would get the same error indexing into an array using a null pointer. I think you get the idea now.

The other relevant information is the code address which led to the fault. In your example that is `0x77e915de`. If you configure your linker to produce a full image map you'll be able to identify which line of code led to the fault. Even better, if you produce debug information then you can attach a debugger.

In general terms this sort of error is known as a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), or an access violation, or a protection fault. Those terms all mean the same thing.